# Add facebook pixel code into magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, facebook

I'm using **magento 2** and I'm trying to add the **facebook pixel code** into it , what's the right file to add it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has not changed much from Magento 1, I reckon you should use the `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml`

NB: don't change that file directly as your changes will be overriden by Magento upgrades, override the template in your theme or module.

Comment: there isn't any file so I can have it on all the pages ?

Comment: @alexcr well isn't the point of the Facebook pixel to track the conversion when a sale is made ?

Comment: yes that is right , than you ! but what if I need a js on every page ? and what if I need a js called only on the home page ?

Comment: @alexcr well that's a different question, please create a new question to address this particular issue ;)

Comment: I've posted another question , here is the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114944/add-call-a-js-file-only-on-the-home-page  thank you for your time !

Answer (score 6):

You need to create your own module to add facebook pixel tracking. Here are few links which could help you create your own module -:

http://www.magento.scommerce-mage.co.uk/create-module-in-magento-2.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/create_component.html

Once you have created your module then you can add **checkout_onepage_success.xml** file under **\view\frontend\layout**
with the following content -:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.success">
            <block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Checkout\Success" name="modulename.checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then add **success.phtml** file under **\view\frontend\templates\checkout**
with the following content -:

```
<?php
$order = $this->getOrder();
$pixelValue     = number_format($order->getBaseGrandTotal(),2);
$pixelCurrency  = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();

<script>
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
  value: <?php echo $pixelValue;?>,
  currency: '<?php echo $pixelCurrency;?>'
});
</script>
```

Then add **success.php** file under **\CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Checkout**
with the following content -:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Scommerce Mage. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Checkout;

/**
 * FB Page Block
 */
class Success extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     */
    protected $_salesFactory;

    /**
     * Checkout session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $salesOrderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $salesOrderFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_salesFactory = $salesOrderFactory;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve current order
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\OrderFactory
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        $orderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        return $this->_salesFactory->load($orderId);
    }
}
```

Hope the above information helps you set up facebook conversation tracking but if you are not a developer then you can buy the following extension.

https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento2-facebook-conversion-audience-tracking.html

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as in version 1.0.

```
checkout/success.phtml
```

Use templates - Be ware any change can be overridden by an upgrade, hence don't change the file directly.

Look here as well:
[Install Facebook Pixel Tracking](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49251/install-facebook-pixel-tracking)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 methods to add pixel code to your Magento 2 website:

- Method 1: Using a free Magento 2 Facebook pixel extension.
- Method 2: using Google Tag Manager.
- Method 3: Manually insert Pixel code
  I recommend using method, using official Facebook extension for Magento 2. You can download this extension here: https://facebook.com/ads/pixel/integration/?integration=magento2

**Full reference for all methods can be found in this tutorial**: https://magentip.com/add-facebook-pixel-magento-2/

Hope this helps!