# Add/call a js file only on the home page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm using magento 2.

**I would like to add or call a js file only on the home page , what is the best file to call it?**

Answer (score 0):

Just create `cms_index_index.xml` file in layout folder of your theme/module with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="yourfile.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

It should work :)

Comment: it doesn't properly works like this, I did the file as you said , and after I uploaded my js file into /pub/static/frontend/Venustheme/yume/en_GB/js folder , and also written the link as /pub/static/frontend/Venustheme/yume/en_GB/js/myfile.js into the code , but doesn't seems to work..

Comment: The link should be only `js/myfile.js`

Comment: tryed also like this , but still doesn't work..