# Magento 2 Pixel Order Tracking on Success Page

Tags: magento2

I am trying to integrate the code below on Success page via either a block or by , but after placing an order, the page will be displayed without CSS and the tracking code is not receiving data.

```
<?php
//-------------------------------------------
// START TAG TRACKING CODE
//-------------------------------------------
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$orderData = $order->getData();
$orderAmount = $order->getSubtotal();
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$currency = $order->getOrderCurrency()->getCode();
$items_string = "";

foreach ($items as $item) {
    //loop through all the items
    //get item category code, quantity & amount in 3 variables and append in thee below string
    $items_string += "&CAT=" + $itemCategoryCode + "," + $itemQty + "," + $itemAmount;
}

?>
```

Could someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This way is for Magento 1.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114936/add-facebook-pixel-code-into-magento-2